# How to Stop JNLP file from being downloaded every time

Tags: jnlp

JNLP that launches the client always downloads the client jar. I want it to only download the client jar if the version is newer than the local cached version.

Comment: Did you have a question?  As an aside, these problems are often caused by invalid JNLP files.  Try validating your JNLP using JaNeLA (http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem, you need to have two files on the "lib" directory under your JRE directory. "deployment.config" and "deployment.properties". this will make the jws understand that its a system deployment and not a deployment every time it is launched.

Code for "deployment.properties" file :

```
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
deployment.system.cachedir=JWS
```

Code for "deployment.config" file :

```
deployment.system.config=file:/D:/Program Files/Java/jre1.5.0_22/lib/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
```

Hope this helps, please update your own JRE lib directory on the  deployment.config file above.

Thanks

Suja.

Comment: When deployed for many users, this solution means that we have to change the tags for all the users. Is there no other way?